# Do I need uplay in order to play Ubisoft games bought on Origin?

Tags: origin, ubisoft-connect

When I buy for example Far Cry 4 via Origin, will I need uplay AND Origin to start in order to play it? Or do you just need Origin OR uplay (which one)?
Was wondering.

Comment: If `uPlay` is mentionned as (one of) the game's DRM(s) yes, you do.  At least that's how it goes for uPlay games bought on Steam.

Comment: that's the question; it isn't mentioned anywhere in the store description, but uplay is required when buying via steam
but now: will i need origin to start in addition or will the game start only via origin without uplay?

Comment: Do you want to know specifically for Far Cry 4?  Or are you asking just generally?

Comment: especially Far Cry 4, but I'd like to know for other releases as well

Comment: We can't answer for Far Cry 4; the game isn't out yet.  The only answer we can give at the moment is just generally.  And that, really, is up to the game.

Comment: well which way would it be with Far Cry 3?

Comment: or is it so that you have to start both services in order to play any game at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I just started Far Cry 4 which I bought from Origin, after launching it from Origin it opens Uplay and ask for CD key. On entering it game is added to Uplay.